# Android cardlibs animation for different card layout

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm experimenting with cardlibs by Gabriel Mariotti from [here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/). My problem is the animations of the swingbottom or any other animation included only in List view animation. The cards are all same (using same layout). I want to use the swingbottom animation on misccard. each card has its own layout.How can i achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way around. With the tips from Gabriel Mariotti himself on the Global and InnerLayout. So I've modified all of my cards to use the same GlobalLayout but different InnerLayout. Lots of modification but it achieved what i wanted. All the cards now can be added into CardArrayList and used with the animation adapter. Hope this will help anyone who has the same goal as i am. Thank you.